# SolusVM + OpenVZ + Second level quotas -- how to enable?

Tags: linux, vps, openvz, quota

I have a lot of CPanel clients and I've seen some host automatically enable secondary level quotas on signup. I was wondering how do I do that?

Do I need to run a script on signup?
Do I need to edit a default container config file?

Thanks.

Comment: First check [the documentation](https://openvz.org/User_Guide/Managing_Resources#Turning_On_and_Off_Second-Level_Quotas_for_Container).

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1):

As Micheal Hampton alluded to in the comments with the [docs](https://openvz.org/User_Guide/Managing_Resources#Turning_On_and_Off_Second-Level_Quotas_for_Container) link you need to enable this at the default container configuration. You're going to want to change the `QUOTAUGIDLIMIT` from the default of 0 to an amount that will cover all the users on a VM. The docs suggest 100, but I usually deploy 1000 as the default to be safe. I've even seen 10,000 used before, so it's really your choice. That will deploy every new VM with quotas enabled.

### *Fixing already provisioned VMs*

What about VMs already provisioned? First, **the container must be powered off**, then issue the `vzctl set "VMID" --quotaugidlimit 1000 --save`. Note that "VMID" is a placeholder for the container ID. Then start the container and you will have the second quotas enabled for use.

### *Fixing cPanel Quotas*

Once you have the quotas enabled you will want to manual force cPanel to refresh the quotas. I would suggest running `vzctl enter "VMID"` to simply gain access to the VM. Again "VMID" is a placeholder for the container ID. Once inside the VM run the cPanel /script command to force the recheck on quotas `/scripts/fixquotas` You should see it force a recheck and will print out all of the quotas the accounts are getting set to. Once you see this you are finished,and cPanel is now showing disk usage correctly.

Comment: Is there anyway to make this auto? It seems like some providers do this with a presetup script. What about under /etc/vz/conf can't I just add something to I guess the default so it becomes auto? And doesn't SolusVM have something that allows you to run a command before the creation of the VM?

Comment: You can add this to the VM template, but to be honest we check to ensure it is enabled with our automated cPanel installer.